# Linking multiple fields in a table to one table

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a SQL database I am trying to query with Crystal reports.

It is a database that houses interventions by pharmacy staff for medications.

The main record table contains three fields called `Drugsinvolved`, `Drugsinvolved2` and `Drugsinvolved3`. These all contain a reference number that refers to a second table for drug name and details.

How should I link these tables together? I've tried both adding 3 versions of the Drug table and linking them separately, and tried making 3 links from `drugs1,2,3` to one Drug table. Neither give me the correct results.

Comment: Instead of writing query... link those tables in crystal and crystal will prepare a query as per your requirement.

Comment: @siva I am also using Crystal reports to link the tables and prepare a query. However, it doesn't provide a satisfactory result either.

Comment: What is the problem with that query generated with CR?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for your purpose:

```
SELECT m.Drugsinvolved, d1.DrugName,
       m.Drugsinvolved2, d2.DrugName,
       m.Drugsinvolved3, d3.DrugName
FROM mainTable m, drugTable d1, drugTable d2, drugTable d3
WHERE m.Drugsinvolved = d1.DrugId
      AND m.Drugsinvolved2 = d2.DrugId
      AND m.Drugsinvolved3 = d3.DrugId
```